# Date Picker in iOS using Swift Programming

Tags: ios, swift

This is  sabarish i am new to swift language

i need to create a date picker when the user clicks on the button .....

button is created in the story board (not dynamically)

Comment: You should google it and start to code first.

Comment: hmmm ok fine... @mhs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code :

```
var datepick=UIDatePicker(frame:CGRectMake(20, 80, 280, 100));
datepick.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date;
self.view.addSubview(datepick);
```

Comment: Thanks Jay Bhalani for your reply ...... i rasied the doubt wrongly.....actual question is i need to create date picker programactically...by the clickng the button...

Comment: it's works fine ...... how to keep the picker below and make the date picker back ground as pure white ..so that user can able see the picker clearly... @ jay bhalani